# Select Dropdown is not working on iPhone iOS version 14.6 in Safari Browser

Tags: ios, iphone, select, dropdown, mobile-safari

I'm using very basic HTML to create select dropdowns. Like

```
<select>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                        <option value="4">Four</option>
                    </select>
```

But when I run my site on iPhone with the 14.6 version. I'm not able to set or change the value of the dropdown. Is there any known issue?
More details: I'm using angular 1.x, boostrap, ASP Dot Net.

Comment: We are doing some testing. It looks like with basic HTML with no JS frameworks, this isn't a problem.

We tested with a React app and it isn't a problem.

It seems to only be happening in Angular 1

Comment: I'll also note, that we've determined this issue is not Safari specific, it happens on Chrome or Safari on the iphone.

Comment: We are working on creating a bare bones simple html file to reproduce this issue. In one test it looks like the act of including ngMaterial as a dependency causes this problem to happen. But if it is just a barebones angular 1 app the problem is not occurring so far.

Comment: @dfritch Actually, the issue is with the fastclick.js file. When I remove the code and js file reference from my index page related to fastclick it's both simple and the ng-option/ ng-repeat dropdown starts working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my index.aspx page I'm using the fastclick.min.js and above the line of code in the document.ready block.

```
var attachFastClick = Origami.fastclick;
attachFastClick(document.body);
```

So basically what I did, trace down the index file from top to bottom for the script code which might be the cause for this dropdown issue. So commented out the line of code that might be the cause for the issue and then tested on iOS 14.6 device for safari browser.
As soon as I commented out the code related to fast click and check on iphone iOS
14.6 it starts working.

I'm not sure why the drodown is not working on iPhone iOS 14.6 safari browser when with fastclick.js include.

Answer (score 1):

### **EDIT (Aug 13, 2021)**

This is Apple's response to the bug report.

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:
>
> Please know that this is fixed in iOS 15, as we changed the UI for <select> elements.
>
> iOS 15 beta 5 (19A5318f)
> https://developer.apple.com/download/
>
> ---
>
> For a complete list of logging instructions visit:
> https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/

I've tested iOS 15 Beta in the Xcode simulator, and this is not an issue. So with the next release of iOS this will hopefully be resolved for anyone else who was having trouble.

### Original Answer

It seems this is likely an issue with the latest iOS release.

I will submit a bug to Apple and update this answer with what I hear from them.

Our Angular 1.x application was working fine until 14.6 was released, then iPhones specifically started having issues, both in Chrome and Safari (Android appears unaffected, and desktop computers also work fine. As far as we know, this is only a problem with iOS). When the user selects an input from the drop-down and then presses "Done", it updates the selection only sometimes. Most of the time, the old option remains selected, but occasionally, it will be updated with the new one. Using the up/down arrows seems to work only slightly better, but still only persist the selection sometimes.

I am able to reproduce the problem using the simple example below.
Testing shows that running Angular 1.x and certain other dependencies on iOS 14.5 or 14.6 causes the problem.
Angular 1.x by itself does not cause a problem.

Known dependencies that cause problems so far:

Onsen UI version 1.3.17. (version 2.11.2 seems to work fine).

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@1.3.17/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="BasicCtrl">
        <select>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="selectedOpt" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in opts">
        </select>
        <div>{{'{name: ' + selectedOpt.name + ', id: ' + selectedOpt.id + '}'}}</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.config(function() {});
      app.controller('BasicCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.opts = [
          {id: 1, name: "A"},
          {id: 2, name: "B"},
          {id: 3, name: "C"},
          {id: 4, name: "D"},
          {id: 5, name: "E"},
          {id: 6, name: "F"}
        ];
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

System specs:
macOS Big Sur Version 11.4

Model Name:   MacBook Pro

Model Identifier: MacBookPro13,3

Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7

Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz

Number of Processors: 1

Total Number of Cores:    4

L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB

L3 Cache: 6 MB

Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled

Memory:   16 GB

XCode simulator:

Version 12.5 (961.1)

SimulatorKit 609

CoreSimulator 757.5

iPhone 12 Pro Max

iOS 14.5

Comment: Thank you @NiFiNiTe for your answer. Actually, the issue is with the fastclick.js file. When I remove the code and js file reference from my index page related to fastclick it's both simple and the ng-option/ ng-repeat dropdown starts working properly.

Comment: I have a similar issue with new Iphon 14 Pro max (latest update on this date 09/05/2023). The simple native html select element not working! So it's not a angular or react issue. Im using styled-components, but have same behaivor with plain <select>

Comment: @northernwind If you are using iOS 15 or later, I'm guessing you are experiencing an issue that is different than the one in this thread. Or, perhaps this issue has resurfaced?

Comment: @NiFiNiTe You are right! The issue is different. To be clear, I'm not able to select some option, cause my option writed as: `<option value="someValue" label="label_for_value"></option>` .

But for iOS to works properly it need to be:  `<option value="someValue">label_for_value</option>`

Comment: @northernwind I would recommend opening a new question for that issue if you are still having trouble with it since it's most likely unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
This problem was with angular-material

Tell the AngularJS Material Gesture module to skip (or ignore) click hijacking on mobile devices.

$mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();