# Buildfire - IOS Dropdown

Tags: buildfire

The IOS dropdown list does not accept the new value when done is clicked.
For Example, I scroll to the wanted value, click done, nothing happens.
Anything I can do to force the dropdown list to work?

```
<select flex="55" layout-align="start center" style="background: none;  font-weight: bold;" ng-model="x.workout">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Select Workout</option>
     <option ng-value="x.title" ng-repeat="x in lbWorkouts track by $index" selected>{{x.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of your plugin ?

Comment: @blue every <select> has this issue. unless you touch Done in the IOS picker perfectly.  This wasn't the case in the past.

Comment: it seems to be an issue with angularJS and the iOS 14.6 update. check this SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983139/select-dropdown-is-not-working-on-iphone-ios-version-14-6-in-safari-browser